# Relationship types in a MySQL Workbench EER diagram with "Classic" notation

Tags: database, mysql-workbench, erd

[image]

Their is two relationship.Rel_01 and Rel_02

In Rel_01 diamond is half filled
Rel_02 diamond is full filled.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

The diamond shows **cardinality**. `Rel_01` is *one-to-many* and `Rel_02` is *one-to-one*. The filled (or *black*) side is the `1` side and the unfilled (or *white*) side is the `1..*` side.